# Java Spring Boot plus Spring Batch create Jar and run specific job only

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, spring-batch

I am trying to have a spring boot with spring batch app, which would have multiple jobs.

When I am trying to build the jar (assuming only one job) it still starts the app and actually runs the available job.

```
mvn clean package
```

I am just trying to build a Jar here, do not want to actually run any Job.

Later, once the Jar is available, I can pass some arguments to run a specific Job. For now I have only one job in my code, will have more later. But I am unable to run even one job.

This is what I tried so far based on all online suggestions.

BatchConfiguration.java

```
@Configuration
@EnableBatchProcessing
public class BatchConfiguration {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(BatchConfiguration.class);

    @Autowired
    public JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory;

    @Autowired
    public StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory;

    @Autowired
    public FileDTO fileDTO;


    @Bean
    public Job fetchJob(Step step) {
        return jobBuilderFactory
                .get("My Job")
                .incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
                .flow(step)
                .end()
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public Step getData() {
        return stepBuilderFactory
                .get("get data")
                .<FileDTO, FileDTO>chunk(1)
                .reader(FileReader())
                .processor(new FileProcessor())
                .writer(new FileWriter())
                .build();
    }
}
```

application.properties

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://dbhost:1000/db
spring.datasource.username=username
spring.datasource.password=password
spring.datasource.platform=postgresql
spring.batch.job.names=
```

I tried to give blank here for spring.batch.job.names property.

Ran the **mvn clean package**, which helped me compile and build jar without running the job.

Now, I am trying to run giving the parameter,

```
java -jar target\mytest-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar --spring.batch.job.names=fetchJob
```

It does not start the job at all.

Please note that if I remove the property spring.batch.job.names from application.properties and follow the steps, **mvn clean package** => will run the job and create the Jar. Which is what I don't want.
As later I will have more jobs, which I do not want to run while creating the Jar.

What am I missing here?

Comment: `mvn clean package` doesn't run your job, but any Junit test with `@SpringBootTest` annotation does. Try to setup your `application.properites` with jobs and run: `mvn clean package -DskipTests`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I am just trying to build a Jar here, do not want to actually run any Job.

Instead of adding the empty property `spring.batch.job.names=`, you need to set the property `spring.batch.job.enabled=false` for that.

> It does not start the job at all.

If you remove the empty property `spring.batch.job.names=` and run your job with:

```
java -jar target\mytest-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar --spring.batch.job.names=fetchJob
```

then it should work.